# Creating a datalayer event push user inputs, the for is FreeForm Pro

Tags: solspace-freeform

How do I set up datalayer event to push user form data to use on Google Ads and Analytics?

Form is from Freeform Pro in ExpressionEngine 5. after submission users are redirected to a thank you page.

Went through a range of solutions using GTM. Seemingly using the HTML code from Elements in Devtools on Google can't seem to track this way.

Do I need to insert the code for the datalayer event and push into the form itself. and what would that code look like.

Or is GTM set up need to be different cause the form is a plugin.